# How to change JSON API label into number in .net

Tags: reactjs, .net, react-simple-maps

So currently I'm using react-simple-map to make a map that with marker. It required this json format:

```
[{
   "coordinates":{
      "0":139.6917,
      "1":35.6480
   },
      "name":"Tokyo",
  },
  {
    "coordinates":{
      "0":101.9758,
      "1":4.2105
    },
    "name":"Malaysia",
}]
```

Then I'm trying to change the label in .net like this:

```
 public IQueryable<Object> GetCoordination()
        {
            return from a in _awContext.SalesTerritories
                   join p in _awContext.Coordination
                   on a.TerritoryId equals p.TerritoryID
                   select new
                   {
                       id = a.TerritoryId,
                       coordinates = new 
                       {
                           '0' = p.Lat,
                           '1' = p.Long,    
                       },
                       name = a.Name,
                       countryRegionCode = a.CountryRegionCode,
                       salesYtd = a.SalesYtd,
                       salesLastYear = a.SalesLastYear,
                       costYtd = a.CostYtd,
                       costLastYear = a.CostLastYear,

                   };
        }
```

**What happen is the 0 & 1 have error.**

Is there anyway to make it integer.

Answer (score 0):

you should not have array key

```
{
    "coordinates": [0.1234,1.2345]
}
```

Cheers !

Comment: "lat": 139.6917,
"long": 35.64. The json became like this. if I do coordinates =  new { p.Lat, p.Long },

Comment: Are you tested this? : coordinates = [p.Lat, p.Long]

Comment: Yes this 1 return invalid expression "["

Comment: so i changed it to coordinates = new { p.Lat, p.Long }